# SQL Find unused table in the past 30 days

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table that has table_name, create_time, run_time, query. I would like to generate a list of tables that have not been used in the last 30 days and
a ranking of the tables most used in the last 30 days.

I know how to extract a table within 30 days with BETWEEN but I do not know how to extract those who are not used in those 30 days.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: "Not used in those 30 days" That means the create_time is older than 30 days ago, so that's just a simple `Column < {SomeDate}` comparison. If you want a more specific answer, you need to provide more specific information like your dbms, create table/insert sample data statements and expected results

Comment: Rather `last_used < CURRENT_DATE - 30 days` something.

Answer (score 0):

Minor changes might be needed depending on your DBMS, but this should very close

### Tables Without Queries in Past 30 Days

```
SELECT table_name,MAX(run_time) AS LastQueryDate
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY table_name 
HAVING MAX(run_time) <= '2022-02-01' /*Hard coded date for simplicity. Could also parameterize as current date - 30 days*/
```

### Most Used Tables over Past 30 Days

```
SELECT TOP(10) 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS UsageRank
      ,table_name
      ,COUNT(*) As QueryCount
FROM YourTable
WHERE run_time BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-03-01'
GROUP BY table_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```